# Android studio not recognizing Facebook library

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded the new Android Studio to my mac and tried importing my projects to it without creating a `gradle` file for them (since I had some issues importing it, and I saw it's not necessary).

I went to file>import and chose my parent project, imported all the libraries to the project yet still I get this error:

```
import com.facebook.Session;
```

> Cannot resolve symbole 'Session'

any thoughts on how to successfully import this into the new IDE?

Answer (score 5):

As I just learned you have to to it like on IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE:

1. Open *Project Structure* (Press F4 on your project).
2. Select *Modules* on the left pane.
3. Choose your project and you will see *Dependencies* TAB above the third Column.
4. Click on the plus sign in the bottom. Then a tree-based directory chooser dialog will pop up, navigate to your folder containing facebook jar, press *OK*.
5. Press *OK*.

Answer (score -1):

If the library is in the /libs-directory just right-click the jar and click 'Add as library'. This will add the library to your classpath.